# How to catch IllegalArgumentException in tests using thrown-with-msg?

Tags: unit-testing, macros, clojure

I try to test the throw of an exception:

```
;;; src
;; Courtesy https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj
(defmacro assert-args [& pairs]
  `(do (when-not ~(first pairs)
         (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                 (str (first ~'&form) " requires " ~(second pairs) " in " ~'*ns* ":" (:line (meta ~'&form))))))
       ~(let [more (nnext pairs)]
          (when more
            (list* `assert-args more)))))

(defmacro my-macro []
  (assert-args false "foobar")
  #_(...))

;;; test
(deftest x-fn-test
  (is (thrown-with-msg? IllegalArgumentException #"foo" (my-macro))))
```

But none of the exceptions are caught by the test framework, but are all thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the exception is still thrown, is because the macro `(my-macro)` gets expanded during compile time, which calls the `(assert-args)` macro, thus the exception is thrown during compile time. My mistake was to assume that calling `(my-macro)` in the test will trigger the exception at run time and let the test's `(thrown-with-msg?)` catch it.

So the misassumption was that code for nested macros is only expanded during compile time, not executed. If `(my-macro)` would be a function, this would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your `throw` expression is malformed, you want

```
(throw (IllegalArgumentException. "foo"))
```

Full working code:

```
(ns mytest.core
  (:use clojure.test))

(defn x-fn []
  (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "foo")))

(deftest x-fn-test
  (is (thrown-with-msg? IllegalArgumentException           #"foo"     (x-fn)))
  (is (thrown-with-msg? IllegalArgumentException           #".*foo.*" (x-fn)))
  (is (thrown-with-msg? IllegalArgumentException           #"^foo$"   (x-fn)))
  (is (thrown-with-msg? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException #"foo"     (x-fn)))
  (is (thrown-with-msg? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException #".*foo.*" (x-fn)))
  (is (thrown-with-msg? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException #"^foo$"   (x-fn))))


; nREPL 0.1.8-preview
user> 
#<Namespace mytest.core>
mytest.core> (run-tests)

Testing mytest.core

Ran 1 tests containing 6 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
{:type :summary, :pass 6, :test 1, :error 0, :fail 0}
```

Comment: Thanks Joost, but it was just a typo while posting it. The issue remains. Or does it then work for you?

Comment: Hej Joost, I got trapped by the "example fallacy" and simplified my example code to an extend that it didn't illustrate the issue I had. Thus the example worked for you. Now I posted a pretty close example version of my code and that should expose the misassumption. During the process of converging the example to the original code I finally understood what was going on. I still up voted your answer to credit your efforts in helping out.